# What can I do when VS code can NOT save file to SSH remote server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I have made some code works today with VS Code. Suddenly when I pressed the `CMD + s`, VS Code told me:

```
Failed to save 'example.py': Unable to write file

remote+123.255.255.255/data/example.py' (Canceled: Canceled)
```

The SSH connection looks like still alive when I opened another SSH remote project.
Then I thought maybe a backup would be a good idea, So I pressed the `Saved As` button right bottom and input the path `/data/example_backup.py` which got a warning:

```
Please enter a path that exists
```

I still got this warning even if I tried `/data/example.py`.

Then the `show local` button reminded me that I can save this file to my local disk. After pressed `show local` button and choose the local directory, VS Code made some feedback:

```
Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote+123.255.255.255/data/example.py' (Canceled: Canceled)
```

But it seems that the backup worked because the file has already been in the local folder.

Is there a workaround to reconnect the SSH remote and save again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is followed, for instance, by [`microsoft/vscode-remote-release` issue 5215](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5215) (after hibernation) or [4686](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4686)/[3158](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3158) (WSL2)

For  testing, try the `Reload Window` command, and see if the connection is restored then (with your file in progress being restored as well, ready to be saved).

Comment: The connection restored after typing ```Reload Window``` in the ```Cmd + Shift + P``` menu. I prefer vscode add a ```Reload Window``` button or option when ```Cmd + s``` failure appears. Thanks very much, VonC.